# Вывести в таблицу поле из другой по последней записи

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Помогите вывести в таблицу Users поле из Таблицы UserHistories TeamId по ключу UserId. При чём TeamId должен быть последним по UserId из таблицы UserHistories.

```
SELECT TOP 1 TeamId FROM UsersHistoryes WHERE UserId=94 ORDER BY UserHistorysId DESC
```

Вот так вывод по одному пользователю... А надо для всех.
Не знаю вложенный запрос или объединение делать. Я запутался.

```
SELECT Users.UserId, UserFullName, UserLogin, TeamId FROM Users
    INNER JOIN UserHistories ON UserHistories.UserId = Users.UserId
    --WHERE Users.UserId=Users.UserId   
    --Group BY Users.UserId
            ORDER BY Users.UserId
```

Можно и наоборот отфильтровать таблицу UserHistory так чтобы остались только последние записи по UserId. Просто эта манипуляция нужна, чтоб потом связать ее с другой таблицей корректно.

P.S. По дате цепляться нельзя. Она не всегда есть, и может быть разной.

[image: TeamId]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов:

```
SELECT Users.UserId, UserFullName, UserLogin, 
(SELECT top 1 teamid FROM UserHistories WHERE UserId=userlogin ORDER BY UserHistoryID DESC) TeamId 
FROM Users
```

[Пример работы](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63c76/1)